# Laravel 4.2 composer update error

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I try the composer update command but I get this error:

```
Removing mockery/mockery (dev-master 96a8596)
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete .../vendor/mockery/mockery/tests/Mockery/ContainerTest.php
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permissions issue. You could try deleting the `/vendor` directory and running composer update again.

```
cd path/to/project
rm -rf vendor
composer update
```